# How Do I Access An Element from Within Another Element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, element

I'm building a website and I need to access an element with a specific class name from another element but I have used this class name within other groups.

```
    <div class="1">
Object 1
<div class="hair">Black</div>
</div>
<div class="2">
Object 2
<div class="hair">Brown</div>
</div>
<div class="3">
Object 3
<div class="hair">Red</div>
</div>
```

How would I access the hair for solely Object 3?

Could someone please provide a solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: in what way "access"? a query selector? `".3 .hair"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access this element with CSS, you can simply use the parent class.

```
.3 .hair{}
```

If you are trying to get this object in JS, you have two choices. The first one is to use vanilla js.

```
//+ES6
document.querySelector(".3 .hair").innerText;
//Red

//---------

//vanilla js
document.getElementsByClassName("3")[0].getElementsByClassName("hair")[0].innerText;
//Red
```

The second choice is jQuery. It's like using the query selector.

```
$(".3 .hair").text();
//Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the parents class before the child

```
const el = document.querySelector(".3 .hair")
```